# Github desktop: Can two different people use the same machine with two different accounts.

Tags: git, github

Two different people, with two individual accounts, using the same machine, and needing to separately use Github desktop to make commits. 
 So all the answers I have found deal with two accounts of the same person, typically a personal and a company account. This case is different. Me and my partner have to share the same machine, there is no way around this at the moment. We have our individual accounts that are not related. I downloaded Github desktop and logged in with my account first, which created the github folder on the machine, and i have been using it without a problem. However, is there a way for my partner to log me out, use it under her account, have a separate github folder for her repos, and then log out when done? Simply trying to log my account out from the options menu didn't seem to do anything. 
 [gihub desktop log out screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko8UW.png)

Comment: Do you and your partner have different OS-level accounts? (For a variety of reasons you definitely should.) In that case logging out of the OS and letting your partner log into here OS-level account should give you the isolation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Things you can do:

1. Create 2 different users in windows for your friend and yourself. As the key for github remains under USER_HOME\.ssh thus, each user will have separate space to recognize it.
   Also the gitCOnfig too will be individuals for individual users.
2. In case you don't want 2 different users for windows, then the solution is bit tricky.
   While committing code, put your git user name in commit message. While your friend works, she need to put her git user name. Thus, individual commits are in their own name.

Comment: I-m going to try option number 1 and see how that works. Thanks

Comment: Please let me know what happens.

Comment: Yes, number 1 was the right choice. Simply create separate accounts in windows or the OS you use and that's it.